# Email Templates when sending invoices

Tags: message-templates

I have created an email template for when I send out my invoices. I can't seem to integrate it into the invoice email.

When I send out my invoices by email in CiviCRM I have the option to add email content as in the body of my email. I would like to use a template that I have created for this email being sent out with the invoices. The templates as you know can be added when a person has registered for an event but I can't seem to use a template for sending out my invoice. The invoice is an attachment, so I don't want to write the body of the email every time.

Comment: This question is a little unclear.  Could you say a bit more about what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: When i send out my invoices by email in Civi i have the option to add email content as in the body of my email.
I would like to use a template that i have created for this email being sent out with the invoices. 
The templates as you know can be added when a person has registered for an event but i cant seem to use a template for sending out my invoice. 
The invoice is an attachment, so i dont want to write the body of the email every time.

Answer (score 1):

As you have surmised, the option to select a template when emailing an invoice from the contribution is not currently an available feature but it is an interesting feature request. I took the liberty of creating the feature request on JIRA on your behalf: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19155

Kind regards,
Tamar